# Why is sscanf not working here?

Tags: c, scanf, cs50

I am doing a problem set based on c language. Source code gets compiled without any syntax error and I am pretty sure about the symantics too. I tried to spot the error using GDB. This is where I noticed the the content at the adress pointed by the tempstorage chances at each iteration but the first int remains the same ( i.e. 0 ). 
This is recover.c problem in the cs50 course. I had posted the previous versions of the same program at cs50-stackexchagne but the answers wheren't much helpful. Thank you

```
/**
 * recover.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 4
 *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{   
    FILE* sdcard = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    // to check if the file is opened correctly or not
    if ( sdcard == NULL)
    {
        printf("corrupted sd card");
        return 1;
    }
    // file pointer to point to the temporary jpg
    FILE* tempjpgg;
    // for the nomenclauture of the jpg photos
    char* jpegname = (char*)malloc(8);
    // to read 512 bytes of data at a time from the sdcard
    char* tempstorage = (char*)malloc(512);
    int firstint;
    int i = 0;
    for (fread(tempstorage, 512, 1,sdcard); ; )
    {
        sscanf(tempstorage, "%d", &firstint); // to make the checking process easier
        if ( firstint >= 0xffd8ffe0 && firstint <= 0xffd8ffef)
        {
            fclose(tempjpgg);
            sprintf(jpegname, "%03d.jpg", i);
            tempjpgg = fopen(jpegname, "w");
            fprintf(tempjpgg, "%d", firstint);
            fwrite( tempstorage, 508, 1, tempjpgg);
            i++;
        }
        else if ( i != 0)
        {
            fprintf(tempjpgg,"%d", firstint);
            fwrite(tempstorage, 508, 1, tempjpgg);
        }
        fread(tempstorage, 512, 1, sdcard);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the integer value in the data in the JPEG file stored as a string or as a binary value — are there 4 bytes that represent the integer directly, rather than a string with n digits in it.  There are a fair number of JPEG recovery program questions for CS50 on SO.  Try a search on SO '`[cs50] jpeg is:q`' to see what others have done or asked about (13 questions, including yours).

Comment: first you're opening binary files in text mode. But the real problem here is that you write text representation of numbers in binary files! Also you're comparing unsigned with signed (0xffxxxxxx) ... and there's endianness to handle when writing integers as binary. Good luck...

Comment: You need to initialise: `FILE* tempjpgg = NULL;` otherwise the first time you call `fclose(tempjpgg)` you'll get UB (most likely a crash). You also have a serious lack of error checking on various calls which can potentially fail.

Comment: @PaulR: Calling `fclose()` with a null pointer is UB already.  Don't call `fclose()` with anything other than a non-null value returned by `fopen()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you're right of course - OP needs to init to NULL *and* test for non-NULL before calling fclose() *and* set the file pointer to NULL after calling fclose().